# How to define a good repository interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following situation:

I'm collecting data on hosts.
Each host has collections of properties and statuses.
and the hosts are gathered in groups.

Each group has a unique ID and each host has a unique ID

and all the groups are gathered in a single "repository".

I'm currently using the following data structure:

```
public class Host {
    private final Map<PropertyId, Property> properties;
    private final Map<StatusId, Status> statuses;
}

public class Group {
    private final Map<HostId, Host> hosts;
}

public class AllGroups {
    private final Map<GroupId, Group> groups;
}
```

This is currently implemented as a regular in memory data structure
but I need to save all this in a data base.
I want to define a good abstraction that would allow me:

- To read each item
- to create update and delete properties and statuses
- to add and delete hosts
- to delete groups

I read some posts regarding the repository pattern and it seems appropriate, but I can't figure out how to define the interfaces correctly

Should I have 1 repository interface?
Or should I have separate interfaces for HostRepository, PropertyRepository StatusReporitory...

Comment: Since "each group has a unique ID and each host has a unique ID", I would expect to see an "id" field in the Host and Group classes.

Comment: Something like this (https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/03/ddd-repository-implementation-patterns/) is worth a read. Bear in mind that DDD takes Fowler's pattern and adds additional nuances to it. E.g. only aggregate roots are available via a repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can have separate repository interfaces, but here's an approach using just one.

These classes could easily be mapped to tables (or documents in a NoSQL DB).

```
public class Property {
  private String name;
  private Object value;
}

public class Host {
  private long id;
  private List<Property> properties;
  private List<Property> statuses;
}

public class HostGroup {
  private long id;
  private List<Host> hosts;
}

public interface HostRepository {

  List<HostGroup> getAllGroups();
  HostGroup getGroupById(long id);
  HostGroup saveGroup(HostGroup HostGroup);
  boolean deleteGroup(HostGroup HostGroup);

  Host getHostById(long id);
  Host saveHost(Host host);
  boolean deleteHost(Host host);

  Property getProperty(long hostId, String propertyName);
  void saveProperty(long hostId, Property property);
  ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if when saving a property we also need to specify the node relationship. the property is added to a host that exist in a node, would you do something like this?

void saveProperty(NodeId nodeId, HostId hostId, Property property);

Comment: If the property's host is related to the same node in question, then you only need the host's ID when saving the property.  It would be redundant to do otherwise since you can lookup the property's node via its host.